# Can I add nodes during the mapping stage of Neo4j ETL Tool

Tags: neo4j

I have imported data from my RDBMS to neo4j using the neo4j ETL tool present in neo4j desktop. The tool has automatically generated 4 nodes  entities and 3 relationships for me based on the 6 tables in my relational database that I am imported data from. However I want to change one of those relationships into a node or add another node label. Is this possible and if so how do I do it

I was expecting 5 node labels but the tool has generated only 4 . The generated graph is not wrong…. But I want to modify it such that one of the relationships is converted into a node entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot tell the Neo4j ETL tool how to decide what becomes a node or relationship, as configuring that would not be straightforward and would greatly complicate the tool implementation.

*But you can certainly change the data model using Cypher *after* the data is generated. If you want to do that, create a new question with full details of the currently generated data model and what you want the new data model to be.*

Comment: Thanks,I have tried your approach for a small database and it worked.But I actually have to import 2000 tables from MySql to neo4j ...so in my opinion the approach you have mentioned will be quite cumbersome....A few sites have stated details of configuration using a mapping.json file.Will that help me in configuration?If not can I know in which case I am to use that.I am not able to get a clear idea from the sites that I have visited.

Comment: Have you looked at all the [different ways to import from a relational DB](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/data-import/relational-to-graph-import/#relational-import-tools)?

Comment: Yes,I have.It is from that page that i decided to look into APOC libraries instead of the ETL Tool.But it does not give the information I wanted about mapping.json file.

Comment: What is the "mapping.json" file you refer to? Where did you see that? Should this really be a separate SO question?